# How to reduce data redundancy of text field in database

Tags: database, olap, redundancy

I am using a OLAP system, some of table has text field. the text length can be from some Bytes to KB, while the size of other fix size fields in one row is only about 100 Bytes.

some of my tables have billions of rows and the value of text field is highly repeatable, how can i reduce this kind of redundancy to save the storage space and does not lose query performance?

Answer (score 1):

*Redundant* is a technical term in database work. It doesn't mean "repeated". It means "unnecessarily repeated".  You probably don't have any unnecessary repetition; each value is required in its own row in order to convey the right meaning to the user.

Sometimes, you can replace existing values with shorter, human-readable codes. Shorter codes make narrower tables, which implies more rows per page in the database, and faster I/O. For example, in the USA, we often use the two-letter postal code for the state instead of the state's full name. This almost always works. (Meaning humans can read the output without further processing, and queries run at least a little faster.)

Sometimes, you can replace existing values with a surrogate key, hoping that the cost of the additional join will be outweighed by faster disk I/O.  Sometimes this tactic *doesn't* work; you need to test and be prepared to revert to your original schema.

Comment: Thanks, actually, my values are some url strings, it is repeated in a low frequency, say 10~100 times per each (not as much as postcode) . the reason I want to reduce them is these values occupy most of my storage spaces, it means if I can reduce repeated values into one , it will save upto 80% disk spaces.
I tried to use a key-value storage as you said and did join when query comes in. but it leads lots of random access for the addition key-value storage, which make the query performance decrease a lot. is there any optimization work I can do here?

Comment: a) To shorten a URL, you might be able to use a service like [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/), [bitly](https://bitly.com/), or [Google URL shortener](http://goo.gl/). b) You might be able to just replace `http://www.` with nothing. A URL that doesn't start with `http://www.` would need to have that string prepended to it on output.

Answer (score 0):

URLs in reporting DBs have caused me troubles before.  Something may be worth trying would be to split the URL into 3 pieces - hostname/port, path & querystring - you might end up with a url-fragment table (possibly more than one), and a URL table with FKs to the URL-fragment table. Sometimes the querystring is not worth storing separately, in which case the URL-table has FKs for hostname & path, and stores the querystring.

Another idea is to chop out useless parts of the querystring - this decision needs to happen on an application-by-application basis, but can make a big difference - removing session IDs from URLs can improve things dramatically (also, you can probably chop out google analytics parameters.

Also, only access the URL tables when you need to, and make sure you have indexes on at least the hostname.